# Is it illegal to possess jiggler keys?

Tags: criminal-law, pennsylvania

A friend of mine gave me his keys to his vehicle so I could clear off the front seat. My friend was not with me at the vehicle at this time, but I was taking a book bag from the front seat, moving it to the trunk when I was approached by law enforcement and after being detained and being searched and patted down they removed the keys off my belt loop. On the keyring were 7 **jiggler keys** and I was arrested and **charged** with **manufacture etc motor vehicle master keys, possession of an instrument of crime with intent.** Fast forward to my preliminary hearing, and the charge *possession of an instrument of crime with intent was *dismissed** but the other was held. Now in the state of ***Pennsylvania it says that having lock pick tools in your possession can be illegal if used in a crime or intent to be used in a crime.*** Since the possession of an instrument of crime with intent charge was dropped then wouldn’t that eliminate the other charge and prove my innocence to dismiss the case altogether since possessing the keys isn’t illegal unless used in a crime or with intent?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very poorly written law! Unless they have defined 'fit' elsewhere as completely different to an ordinary interpretation of that word. A master key is designed to *operate* two or more locks with different normal keys using the same action as a normal key. I assume the omitted exceptions were about vehicle manufacturers or supply chain vehicle handlers or logistics companies who have legitimate reasons for requiring master keys (though I don't know if they actually make these in reality, as they diminish the security of a lock). Possibly locksmiths were included as well, but I doubt it as vehicle companies are not in the habit of granting locksmiths master keys for all their vehicles.

By the above definition, literally any key that fits in the lock is a 'master key'. Even if we assume 'fit' is supposed to imply 'operate as the lock's specific key would', it's still completely absurd to define a jiggler as a 'master key'. You can open a lock with a piece of bent wire if you're determined and skilled enough. Or a drill, for that matter. A jiggler key is a tool ('lockpick tool', and therefore potentially an 'instrument of crime' if you intended to use it as such), not a master key. If you include this in your definition of 'master key', where do you stop? Bent wires? Drills? Someone else's worn car key that doesn't match this vehicle's key but conceivably could be used if jiggled around enough?

If your lawyer can't find suitable precedent refuting this mistaken definition, then you should be able to find a vehicle locksmith who will provide expert evidence that a jiggler is not a master key.

Comment: Welcome to Law.SE.  Can you cite any authority that this is _not_ how Pennsylvania interprets that law?

Comment: *"A master key is designed to operate two or more locks with different normal keys using the same action as a normal key."* - actually, this legislation defines what it means by the term "master key", and includes no such criteria that the "action used" must be that of an ordinary key. A "piece of bent wire", despite fitting the lock, may not be a master key because it does not seem to be a key at all - if however a piece of bent wire were treated as a key, and if it was specifically adapted to open multiple locks, then under the legislation it would appear to be a "master key".

Comment: @Steve "actually, this legislation defines what it means by the term "master key", and includes no such criteria that the "action used" must be that of an ordinary key." Umm... Yes it does. It says a master key is "any KEY adapted to fit..." If its not a key its not a master key. Things used unlike keys are not keys. Therefore things used unlike keys are not master keys.

Comment: @Matt, yes, we're already in agreement that if it's not a key of any sort, then it cannot be a master key. But I don't agree that a jiggler key is being used "unlike a key". I accept it is not being used in the normal "turnkey" fashion like a freshly manufactured, but it is not beyond experience to jiggle an ordinary key (in fact I have two locks at home that almost always require jiggling), and in the case of a jiggler key, the ability to jiggle over a wide range is exactly it's adaptation compared to an ordinary key. (1/2)

Comment: Moreover, if your definition were accepted, that a key must fit the lock exactly and turn without special technique, then it would seem impossible for an adapted master key to even exist. Rather, the locks themselves would have to be adapted to accept more than one exact key profile, meaning that it is the lock that would carry the adaptation to be opened by multiple keys (which need not themselves be master keys capable of operating multiple locks), not the key adapted to open multiple locks. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve If your master keying is set up poorly a regular key can be modified to become a master key. The law would prohibit that. But if I accept that being "adapted" (meaning modified) is required, a master key directly manufactured as a master key isnt adapted for anything and therefore isnt a master key by this definition, which is absurd. I think the word "adapted" just means designed/made for a certain purpose.

Comment: @Matt, I think a master key manufactured as such is still "adapted" - I'm interpreting the word in the sense of "made suitable for the purpose of being a master key" rather than "modified after manufacture". Crucially, as I previously suggested, this rules out cases where the key does in fact fit multiple locks (which is technically true of almost any mass-market lock and key system), but there was never any intention that the key should be used as a master key.

Answer (score 0):

The "manufacture etc." law seems to be [this one](http://cshawndryer.com/?page_id=350):

> § 909. Manufacture, distribution or possession of master keys for motor vehicles

> (a) Offense defined.– A person commits a misdemeanor of the first degree if he manufactures, distributes, or possesses any motor vehicle master key.

> [inapplicable exceptions omitted]

> (c) Definition.–As used in this section “master key” means any key adapted to fit the ignition switch, trunk or door of two or more motor vehicles, the ignition switches, trunks or doors of which are designed to be operated by keys.

You were in possession of a master key as defined by the law, so you are guilty of the offence.

Comment: Do you have any case law to back up your interpretation? Jigglers take at least a bit of technique to use, and are not expected to directly "fit" any lock, arguably fitting zero locks. By applying the same technique an ordinary key could likewise open locks it doesnt directly fit.

Comment: Jigglers need to be jiggled to make the lock operate, if just inseted and turned the normal way they don't unlock a lock unless it is set up to let *any* key open it.

Comment: @Matt, the question is whether they are "adapted to fit...two or more locks". A key which "fits" is arguably any key which operates the lock when inserted and applied *in accordance with the way that key works* - it doesn't seem to me that the technique with the key must be trivial, or that the key must fit in the same way the lockmaker envisaged. With an "ordinary key" however, the question is whether it was ever adapted to fit multiple locks, not merely that it does in fact fit multiple locks (by coincidence, by wear and tear, etc.).

Comment: @Steve Hmm... I think thats a weird definition of "fit". It seems more reasonable to judge if it fits in accordance with the way the lock is expected to work. It is also in the context of a "master key" If the key can't be used the way keys are typically used, is it really a key? Are lockpicks master keys according to this definition? Surely not. If you cant just insert it and turn it, its not a key that fits.

Comment: @Matt, I don't think it is an unreasonable interpretation in the context. A key is any device that operates a lock - and doesn't, for example, smash the lock to pieces. The fact that the "master key" must be jiggled is precisely on account of its adaptation to fit two or more locks - that is, the ability to open multiple locks by a jigging action is precisely *how* that key is designed to work and is positively adapted differently from an ordinary key. It may not fit any given lock well by the engineering standards of lockmakers, but it does fit well enough to open two or more such locks.

Comment: @Steve So lockpicks are master keys under your interpretation?

Comment: @Matt, the question in such cases is whether a pick is a kind of key - if it is a key, then it is undoubtedly a master key under the legislation. Picks are not conventionally considered to be a kind of key, but a "jiggler key" obviously is considered to be a kind of key. Picks in many jurisdictions are also subject to different controls, especially when carried around outdoors with no good reason, whereas the focus here includes the manufacture and distribution of motor vehicle master keys, which appears to be a very specific offence.

Comment: @Steve I agree that if they are keys then they are master keys as defined here. But they are certainly not "obviously" keys. They are in fact obviously not keys. (Since they arent used like a key) Since we clearly disagree on this point I guess we arent going to get anywhere with this.

Comment: @Matt, I think the issue with picks is not that they aren't used like keys (to operate locks). It's that they are physically and practically distinct enough to be considered a separate kind of tool, distinct from the category of keys, and something you use when you *don't* have a key. For example, you don't typically twist a pick to turn the lock, you use a separate tool for that step (either the picking wrench, or perhaps a third tool like a screwdriver to apply gross turning force to fully turn the whole mechanism, once the pins are overcome and the barrel held off-centre in a picked state).

Comment: @Steve Jigglers are also not used like keys. If you dont know and apply the technique it wont work. Like lockpicks they are used when you dont have a key. Nobody uses jigglers when what they really want is a key. The second tool (tension wrench) for lockpicks is not a relevant distinction in deciding if it is a key or not. A pick gun (single tool) is surely not a key either. A bump key? Also not a key. (Despite key being in the name)

Comment: @Matt, I would also add that a "key" tends to have some sort of adaptation to a keyway - a fixed overall profile which forms the body of the key which fits into the lock, as well as having a variable element (which differs between keys) which sets the pins or levers of the lock. Often, the key cannot be withdrawn except when the lock is fully open or closed. A pick is typically not fitted even to the keyway, and can be inserted or withdrawn with the lock in any state, as well as differing for the past-mentioned reason that it is not designed to apply torque.

Comment: @Matt, arguably a pick gun is not a key but another kind of lockpicking tool (again, because of the mechanical differences), but a bump key looks to me like a "key adapted to fit multiple locks", especially because bump keys often start life as a key blank or an ordinary key.

Comment: @Steve Well... A jiggler does not have a fixed overall profile which forms to the body of the lock, does not have variable elements which differ between them (in a set there is variation, but the sets are identical for certain lock types), and you often can remove them when the lock is partially open. This describes jigglers as the lockpcking tools that they are but for some reason you insist they are keys. Designed for torque is not a qualification that makes something a key. Bump keys dont fit any lock. Locks are opened by bump keys when used with proper technique and a hammer like tool.

Comment: @Matt, I guess it may depend on which jiggler keys we are talking about. On the "variable element", I was suggesting that it was the fixed profile fitted to the keyway which seems to be amongst the differences which distinguish a key from a pick. To say "bump keys don't fit any lock" is inconsistent with "locks are opened by bump keys". In my view, a key "fits" a lock if it does in fact open the lock.

Comment: @Steve A key has a fixed profile fitted to the keyway precisely so it doesnt move in the keyway. Jigglers by necessity do not have this. If ability to open a lock makes something a key then lockpicks are keys. Your view is not the normal one.

Comment: @Matt, I didn't say the ability to open a lock makes something a key. I also didn't say that the fit to the keyway had to be "precise", or that this one criteria was decisive. I said that *if* we accept priorly that a given item is a key, then that key's ability to actually open a particular lock means it "fits" that lock. Clearly things other than keys can open locks - picks, for example, can open locks. I also contend that the fit of the key does not have to be mechanically precise, if the imprecision is part of the adaptation of the key which makes it capable of fitting multiple locks.